# php upload and rename images sequentially

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

i have an issue with php image upload.

I've made a form that allows user to upload an image.
Tha image will be renamed, and till now everything's work fine.
that i need is a function that rename my image like this:

image1.(EXT)
image2.(EXT)
image3.(EXT)
...and so on

so i need somthing to increase the number of the uploaded images sequentially, starting from 1.

my code for now is this:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;


 function findexts ($filename) { 
 $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
 $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
 $n = count($exts)-1; 
 $exts = $exts[$n]; 
 return $exts; 
 }


 $ext = findexts ($_FILES['ufile']['name']) ; 
 $target = "images/";
 $target = $target .'image'.$i++.'.'.$ext; 

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$i.$ext;
 } 
 else
 {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 } 

?>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: if the numbers dont reefer to anything just a unique name is all that's needed

Comment: Unless you have more to this script, every time you run the script, you'll reset $i to 0.  This will effectively overwrite any previous uploaded file with the same name ie image0.$ext, image1.$ext.  Unless that is your intent, you should consider storing the name in a database or scanning the directory for all the file names.  Just something to think about.

Comment: i can't use a database in this case.
How to obtain that scanning the directory as you mentioned above?